# 2 внешних ключа к одной Таблцице

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день!
Столкнулся с проблемой имею 2 класса описывающих Entity Framework сущности:

```
    public interface IUser
    {
       string Name { get; set; }
       string Password { get; set; }

       ICollection<ITransaction> InTransactions { get; set; }       
       ICollection<ITransaction> OutTransactions { get; set; }

    }

    public class User : IUser
    {
            public User()
            {
                InTransactions = new HashSet<ITransaction>();
                OutTransactions = new HashSet<ITransaction>();
            }

            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name{ get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<ITransaction> InTransactions { get; set; }    
            public virtual ICollection<ITransaction> OutTransactions { get; set; }
    }


public interface ITransaction
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        int IdUser { get; set; }
        int IdUserCorrespondent { get; set; }
        decimal? In{ get; set; }
        decimal? Out{ get; set; }
        decimal Balance { get; set; }

        IUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
        IUser UserCorrespondent { get; set; }
    }


public class Transaction : ITransaction
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public int IdUserCorrespondent { get; set; }

        public decimal? In{ get; set; }
        public decimal? Out{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CurrentUser")]
        public virtual IUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserCorrespondent")]
        public virtual IUser UserCorrespondent { get; set; }


    }
```

Пытаюсь осуществить запрос

```
var result = _context.Transactions
                    .Include(t=>t.UserCorrespondent )
                    .Where(t => t.IdUser == userId)
                    .ToList();
```

Падаю с ошибкой того, что свойство UserCorrespondent не объявлено навигационным

The EntityType '......Transaction' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'UserCorrespondent '."

По сути я пытаюсь создать два внешних ключа к одной таблице, но все усложняется по причине использования интерфейсов, подскажите как можно разрешить данную проблему ?

Заранее премного благодарен.

Comment: решал такую проблему аннотацией InverseProperty

Comment: если Вы используете `code first` то тогда рекомендую ознакомиться вот с этим [мануалом](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) в частности для ключа рекомендуется использовать запись вида `Id`||`UserId` для внешнего ключа `UserId`, при таком способе в большинстве случаев можно будет обойтись без *Аннотаций*

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, дело в том, что в атрибуте к свойству навигации нужно указывать свойство-идентификатор. Например:

```
public int IdUser { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("IdUser")]
public virtual IUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
```

Или наоборот:

```
[ForeignKey("CurrentUser")]
public int IdUser { get; set; }
public virtual IUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
```

Т.е. Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
public class Transaction : ITransaction
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public int IdUserCorrespondent { get; set; }

        public decimal? In{ get; set; }
        public decimal? Out{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdUser")]
        public virtual IUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IdUserCorrespondent")]
        public virtual IUser UserCorrespondent { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: при использовании `code first` подхода и следованию [соглашению об именовании](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) в большинстве случаев можно было бы обойтись без аннотаций для навигационных свойств